# Implement iteritems function for my custom iterator?

Tags: python, iterator, containers

The objective of the following program is to learn python generators and iterator implementation in order to understand Python magic methods.

I'm stuck implementing the `iteritems()` function. Also, I want to know whether I'm going on right direction or I'm conceptually wrong in understanding of python magic methods.

```
import random

class Random(object):
    """ generate randomised int of specified length --> [r1, r2, r3....] """

    def __init__(self, length = 1, rand_range = 100):
        self.index = 0
        self.generated_range = []
        self.length = length if str(length).isdigit() else 1
        self.rand_range = rand_range if str(rand_range).isdigit() else 100

    def __iter__(self): return self

    def next(self):
        if self.index < self.length:
            item = random.randrange(0, self.rand_range)
            self.generated_range.append(item)
            self.index += 1
            return item
        raise StopIteration

    def __eq__(self, obj):
        if self.length == obj.length and self.rand_range == obj.rand_range:
            return True
        return False

    def __len__(self):
        return self.length

    def __contains__(self, item):
        if not self.index == self.length:
            while self.next(): continue
        if item in self.generated_range:
            return True
        return False

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self.generated_range:
            return key * 100
        raise KeyError

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        raise NotImplemented

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        raise NotImplemented

    def iteritems(self):
        if not self.index == self.length:
            while self.next(): continue
        for item in self.generated_range:
            yield item

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r1 = Random(10)
    print [ r for r in r1]
    print 10 in r1
    r2 = Random(20)
    print r2.iteritems()
```

[CodePAD link](http://codepad.org/WWR4WKOF)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[iteritems](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) is supposed to return a sequence of (key, val) pairs for a dictionary, so I don't think it's appropriate for your class. If you created a descendant of UserDict, then there might be a case to override it.

If you do override iteritems, you should do so by yielding key, value pairs.

Poor programmer's override:

```
def iteritems(self):
    return iter([(x[0], x) for x in "alpha bravo charlie".split()])
```